# How do I access the "displayed" text of a select box option from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

Given the following HTML:

```
<select name="my_dropdown" id="my_dropdown">
<option value="1">displayed text 1</option>
</select>
```

How do I grab the string "displayed text 1" using Javascript/the DOM?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var sel = document.getElementById("my_dropdown");

//get the selected option
var selectedText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

//or get the first option
var optionText = sel.options[0].text;

//or get the option with value="1"
for(var i=0; i<sel.options.length; i++){
    if(sel.options[i].value == "1"){
        var valueIsOneText = sel.options[i].text;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is assuming that there is an id tag on the select box.

Comment: This code is for the selected option, though the .text attribute will work for any of the options (selected or not) once you obtain them from the options[] list.

Comment: @Liam - Cool. There wasn't an id when I left the comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
var mySelect = document.forms["my_form"].my_dropdown;
// or if you select has a id
var mySelect = document.getElementById("my_dropdown");
var text = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: Again, the example code here assumes he wants the selected option.  His example only has one option, so that will work, but the general case would be to provide some other index to options[].

Comment: well thats true but the topic starter didn't defined the initial situation. I assumed he want to get the text of the current selected option. If he wants the text of an option and knows only the value he will have to use a loop. The access method is the same.

Comment: Assumption is correct: I did want the selected option, but I should have said so.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the **selected** option's text:

```
var select = document.getElementById('my_dropdown');
for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if(select.options[i].selected) {
        break;
    }
}
var selectText = select.options[i].text;
```

In Prototype:

```
var selectText = $$('#my_dropdown option[selected]')[0].text;
```

Edit: And jQuery for completeness' sake (assuming jQuery's CSS selector support is roughly equivalent to that of Prototype's):

```
var selectText = $('#my_dropdown option[selected]').get(0).text;
```

Answer (score 1):

The displayed text is a child node of the option node.  You can use:

```
myOptionNode.childNodes[0];
```

to access it, assuming the text node is the only thing inside the option (and not other tags).

**EDIT:**  Oh yeah, as others mentioned, I completely forgot about:

```
myOptionNode.text;
```

Comment: Which other content do you think would be inside an option ?-) It's simply invalid to put anything else inside !-)

Comment: That's true, it is invalid, but I hadn't tested it, so I am not sure what would happen if, for example, you put a <span> inside an option.  Browsers will let you get away with wonky things sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you modified your code a bit to have an id / class on the and were using jQuery you could have something like the following.  It will pop up an alert for each option with the text of the option.  You probably won't want to alert for all the text, but it illustrates how to get at the text in the first place:

```
$('select#id option').each(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

If you use a class instead of an id, then you'd just have to change the 'select#id' to 'select.class'.  If you didn't want to add a class/id there are other ways to get at the select.

I leave figuring those ways out if you want to go that route as an activity for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org), you could get at it like this:

```
$$('#my_dropdown option[value=1]').each( function(elem){
                alert(elem.text);
            });
```

The above is using a CSS selector that says find all **option** tags with **value="1"** that are inside the element that has **id="my_dropdown"**.